# how to implement mongoose FindManyAndDelete in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

I need to implement a function that deletes many mongoose documents and then returns them, kinda like findOneAndDelete() or findByIdAndDelete() but for several documents at once.
I specifically need to return the documents' ids so this function is catered for that.

For now the best I've got is:

```
const searchQuery: Partial<Model> = {...};
const ids: mongoose.Types.ObjectId[] = (await Model.find(searchQuery)).map(({ _id }) => _id);
Model.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: ids } });

return ids;
```

I was looking for an inbuilt function or and option to return from deleteMany(), but I didn't seem to find anything about that.

Comment: `deleteMany` should return a number indicating the number of items removed. If you want to return the deleted `ids` I guess that your current approach is the correct one.

Comment: As written this won't be atomic.